# SQL Server Scalar variable in Inline table valued function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-function

I have a `multi statement table valued function` which I would like to change to an `inline table valued function` for optimization purposes ( I don't really know if that will be an optimization but I want to try that anyway ). My problem is that I have a `scalar variable` which I don't know how to put in my `WITH` statement.

Code example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[function]()
RETURNS 
  @return_table table (id INT,value NVARCHAR(500)) 
    AS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @tmp_table        TABLE(id INT, value VARCHAR(500))
      DECLARE @variable     BIGINT
      INSERT INTO @tmp_table [...insert code...]
      SET @variable = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM @tmp_table)
    INSERT INTO @return_table SELECT id,value FROM @tmp_table WHERE id = @variable
RETURN
```

*This code is an example, the actual function is more complex but the problem is exactly the same*

I could easily change this to a single `WITH` statement like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  [dbo].[function]()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH tmp_table AS (
       SELECT [...Select Code...]
    )
    SELECT id,value FROM tmp_table 
    WHERE id = [variable]
);
GO
```

My problem lies into the `[variable]` which I don't know how to put into the query. Also, the `variable` is used more than once in my function so I'd rather not just replace it with the query.

I also tried this approach:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  [dbo].[function]()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH tmp_table AS (
       SELECT [...Select Code...]
    ), variable = (SELECT MAX(id) value FROM tmp_table)
    SELECT id,value FROM tmp_table 
    WHERE id = (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM variable)
);
GO
```

But is seems like it made the function way slower.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
WITH tmp_table AS (
   SELECT [...Select Code...]
)
SELECT id,value FROM tmp_table WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tmp_table)
```

I would actually just change it to

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROm [whatever]
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Thank you but as I stated, this is not the actual query I use, this is just an example just to point out my problem.